# What is actually universe? only matter or both matter and space?

Tags: general-relativity, big-bang

I have googled for the "meaning of universe" where I found the following:
"all existing **matter and space** considered as a whole; the cosmos. The universe is believed to be at least 10 billion light years in diameter and contains a vast number of galaxies; it has been expanding since its creation in the Big Bang about 13 billion years ago."

Now,I have heard about big bang theory which tells that universe was initially a point of infinite density .But in the above definition I see space is also included in the universe. so if the universe was initially a point then **what was outside that point?** And **how this point is expanding if there is nothing outside it?** That is why I don't understand the balloon analogy also which is expanding in space. But here the universe itself contains the space according the google definition.

Probably I have this question in my mind because I couldn't visualize how the space meets on itself in 3 dimension like earth's surface does on 2 dimension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the universe finite or infinite?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24017/)

Comment: Also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26613/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7359/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the meaning of "universe":

Unqualified, the Universe is *all there is, was, and will be*.  In other words, *there is nothing that is outside of, independent of, stands apart from, the [Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe)*.

> The Universe is commonly defined as the **totality of existence**

However, it is often the case that "universe" is short for "[observable universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe)":

> The observable universe consists of the galaxies and other matter that
>   can, in principle, be observed from Earth in the present day because
>   light (or other signals) from those objects has had time to reach the
>   Earth since the beginning of the cosmological expansion.

...

> Both popular and professional research articles in cosmology often use the
>   term "universe" to mean "observable universe". This can be justified
>   on the grounds that we can never know anything by direct
>   experimentation about any part of the universe that is causally
>   disconnected from us, although many credible theories require a total
>   universe much larger than the observable universe.

Regarding the Big Bang, you ask: *so if the universe was initially a point then what was outside that point?*

This is a [common question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/if-the-universe-is-expanding-what-is-it-expanding-into) and the answer takes some getting used to.  The [metric expansion of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space#What_space_is_the_universe_expanding_into.3F) does *not* require that there be something 'outside' within which space is expanding.

> Regardless of the overall shape of the universe, the question of what
>   the universe is expanding into is one which does not require an answer
>   according to the theories which describe the expansion; **the way we
>   define space in our universe in no way requires additional exterior
>   space into which it can expand** since an expansion of an infinite
>   expanse can happen without changing the infinite extent of the
>   expanse. All that is certain is that the manifold of space in which we
>   live simply has the property that the distances between objects are
>   getting larger as time goes on. This only implies the simple
>   observational consequences associated with the metric expansion
>   explored below. **No "outside" or embedding in hyperspace is required
>   for an expansion to occur.** The visualizations often seen of the
>   universe growing as a bubble into nothingness are misleading in that
>   respect. **There is no reason to believe there is anything "outside" of
>   the expanding universe into which the universe expands.**