# Does the light from my flashlight travel into space?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, scattering, atmospheric-science, estimation

[image]

Does the light from my flashlight travel into space?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I point a torch up, would the photons hit anything?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294449/) Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243565/243965

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is 'yes'. But if we talk about the reality, then most of the light will be scattered and absorbed,reflected by the particles in atmosphere.

Comment: About two-thirds of the sun's radiation reaches the ground on a clear day. For an LED flashlight the inverse path is probably even more efficient since the spectrum falls within the transparent atmospheric windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its intensity will become lesser and lesser. You can learn more interesting light concepts [here].[1](https://sarathiacademy.com/sims/bending-light_en.html)